# Date formatting issue in Android

Tags: java, android

I am facing an issue while converting String to date. `27-Jul-2020` this is my input String for the date.

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date parsedTransactionDate = inputFormat.parse(transactionDate);//transaction date is `27-Jul-2020`
```

It's returing me output `Sun Jul 27 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2020`.
I'm unable to identify the issue

Comment: 27th July of which timezone?

Comment: @MustansarSaeed that was typing error I have corrected it

Comment: What output are you expecting? Your output string will `27-Jul-2020`. Your date object is display timestamp as well

Comment: I'm expecting string `27-Jul-2020` to be converted to as it is in _Date_

Comment: A `java.util.Date` consists of date, time, offset and zone but you're obviously interested in a date only... Why don't you use `java.time.LocalDate` for instance?

Comment: `parsedTransactionDate` is as it should return with the input `27-Jul-2020` that is given. Because you haven't specified any time in the input string, by default `Date` object will be initialized with time `00:00:00` that is start time of new day, that is `12 AM` midnight. And regarding timezone, you might have set timezone of your server to IST, that i s why `Date` object will be initialized with `GMT+05:30` as timezone.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just a date, then, unfortunately, `java.util.Date` is not a good choice. That API is outdated anyway, so I suggest switching to `java.time`. Use `java.time.LocalDate` and a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`, it's a handy and flexible way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // provide a formatter for parsing
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    // parse the example String using that formatter
    LocalDate parsedTransactionDate = LocalDate.parse("27-Jul-2020", formatter);
    // print the default format of a LocalDate
    System.out.println(parsedTransactionDate);
    // or print it using the formatter defined above
    System.out.println(parsedTransactionDate.format(formatter));
    // or print it using a totally different formatter with a different locale
    System.out.println(parsedTransactionDate.format(
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, dd 'de' MMMM uuuu", Locale.FRENCH))
    );
}
```

the output is this

```
2020-07-27
27-Jul-2020
lundi, 27 de juillet 2020
```